# Using the Mercury editor with Rails 3 my html <div> etc tags are getting converted to &lt and &gt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mercury-editor

Not sure how to fix this. should I be using .html_safe?

When the page renders I am getting a lot of:

```
    &lt;div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;
```

which is obviously not what I am after.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CGI.unescapeHTML`

```
<%= CGI.unescapeHTML(content) %>
```